# Virtualbox VMmanage cpuidset - access denied

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

hello I'm trying to install OS X Yosemite on my machine. Running a intel core i5-4210u CPU with Windows 8.1 and Virtualbox 4.3.26. however the installation freezes around 40-50% and doesn't progress anymore. So I am trying to trick it into thinking I have a older CPU.

However when I try the command:

```
    VBoxManage modifyvm <"C:\Users\Jeffrey\VirtualBox VMs\Mac OS X"> --cpuidset 00000001 000306a9 00020800 80000201 178bfbff
```

I get the error message "access is denied". Mind you I am running the Command Prompt as administrator. How do I fix this?
Sorry if this lacks information, request in the comments and I'll update. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried removing the markup? `<>` try without these.

Comment: @TD.512 yes it results in a VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND error. However it should be in that folder

Comment: Slightly off topic, but: you do know that installing OS X on anything other than VMware Fusion on an OS X host is illegal, right?

Comment: @TD.512 somewhat, Apple is somewhat tolerant to creating Hackintosh machines, that's why the site is still up and running whereas other sites get shot down almost instantly

Comment: You could always use VMware Workstation/Player with the VMware Unlocker. Another point: Are you sure your processor supports the instruction sets you're telling VBox to use?

Comment: @TD.512 I presumed so, gonna run some checks on that right now. keeping my eyes on this.